# Are kidneys kosher? If not, why so?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, meat

Can someone please explain why it is what we often see intestines and liver used in kosher foods, but not kidneys?

Regarding the position of the organs, from what I can see in anatomy, the intestines are placed further back (in, say, a cow) than the kidneys, so I assume it's nothing to do with Gid Hanasheh.

Regarding chelev, if we can remove them from over the liver and intestines, surely we also can do it for the kidneys?
Or does the smaller size of the kidneys make it not worth the trouble?

So what gives?
Could it be something to do with the Rabbinical view of the kidneys being linked to morality and emotion???

Comment: Do non-Jews eat kidneys? Is there enough protein in them that it's worth it?

Comment: @robev https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steak_and_kidney_pie

Comment: Is there chelev on liver and intestines that needs to be removed?

Comment: https://summeryule.com/beef-kidney/#:~:text=No%2C%20beef%20kidney%20is%20likely,out%20this%20fat%20removal%20procedure.

Comment: @robev

Yes, plenty of non-Jews eat kidneys.

Comment: @DoubleAA

Yes, there is chelev around the intestines and liver (less on the latter, I think).

Comment: @rosends

'It's not typically commercially viable to carry out this fat removal procedure.'
OK, so they CAN be, but we don't usually bother? Thanks, good to know. 

Seems a waste when we are already doing do for other organs right by them though...

Comment: @ANH can you source that?

Comment: @DoubleAA

'Basically, all cheilev is either found on internal organs of the animal (spleen, stomach, liver), or in the hindquarters (from the eleventh rib and below).'
https://www.etzion.org.il/en/halakha/yoreh-deah/kashrut-and-issur-veheter/blood-and-fat

'Basically, these are the fats on the kidneys and the intestines, etc.'
https://outorah.org/p/5976/

Some just say 'digestive organs', but this typically means 'intestines'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes kidneys are kosher.**

A possible reason they are considered problematic is because they might be viewed as having *ribui dam* - an abundance of blood, due to their appearance. This would cause issues with the salting process. See [Shulchan Aruch Yora De'ah 73](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.73.1) for details on this, under the laws of liver<sup>1</sup>.

In [Siman 74:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.74.1), the Mechaber and Rama discuss kidneys and both permit them. **The Rama mentions there are some who have a custom to not cook the kidneys, and the Beit Yosef brings the Rokeach as forbidding them. The Darchei Moshe also says, as a result, that *lechatchila*, they should not be cooked**<sup>2</sup>.

So in addition to [Avishai's reason](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/134354/31534) (see also [SA Y'D 105:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.105.8)), this may also be a reason you don't see kidneys in some butchers.

---

<sup>1 - To summarise, there is a gemara in [Chullin 110B](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.110b.4) discussing how to prepare a liver for cooking. There is a principle of כבד אוסרת ואינה נאסרת - liver makes other pieces *assur* but does not itself become *assur* (due to its abundance of blood). Abaye asks if liver will *assur* other meat it is cooked with. Rabbeinu Tam understands his question to be "given that the proper way to *kasher* meat is by salting, but with a piece that is *ribui dam*, one shouldn't salt it but use another method, did the Rabbanim worry that by allowing liver *in general*, people might think you can prepare *any* meat without salting?". Rashi takes it further and says that Abaye is actually questioning if *melicha* works at all for these pieces (following the Rosh).</sup>

<sup>2 - I would be very interested to see if there is any connection with these opinions and a *kabbalistic* idea regarding emotions etc. like you ask, but haven't found anything.</sup>

Comment: Thankyou! 

1. I suppose the size of the liver makes the effort more worthwhile. 
Guessing the blood factor would also affect if/how we might eat them raw if wanted... 
https://www.mishnahyomit.com/articles/Beitzah/Eating%20Raw%20Meat

2. Yeah, I figured that since we relate Gid Hanasheh to Jacob's struggle (and it's commonly associated with the concept of desire), something similar might apply here.

Answer (score 5):

I found the following answer [here](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/isnt-round-steak-kidney-available-kosher-store-butcher-tells-not-kosher-surely-animal-kosher-isnt-meat-animal-also-k/):

"The Torah commands us to abstain from eating cheilev (Vayikra 3:17). These are specific fats which are found in the hindquarters of certain animals, sheep and cattle included. While the cheilev can be removed (using a method known as treibering), rendering the remainder of the meat kosher, this is a tedious and time-consuming task which can only be performed by professionally trained rabbis. It is not normally commercially viable to carry out this procedure. Additionally, due to the severity of the prohibition, some communities have adopted a custom of not using the hindquarters at all. This is the predominant custom in the USA, and it is followed by the OU.

As both round steak and kidneys are found in the hindquarters, they are included in this custom."

Comment: What about those who don't have this custom and do eat meat from the back of the animal?

Comment: @fulltime indeed I've grilled kosher kidney for such a person

Comment: Also what about birds? I also see people advising that bird kidneys are problematic and birds have no issur chelev. E.g., https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/82670/jewish/Special-Considerations-for-Koshering-Fowl.htm